# PHP mysqli_fetch_assoc column name value

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, associative-array, associative

I'm working on a generic query viewer, and I have one last problem to solve.

Suppose I have a query that returns the following data...

```
|  Job Code  | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun | 
--------------------------------------------------------
|  1234-567  |  0  |  3  |  2  |  5  |  2  |  0  |  0  |
|  3214-431  |  0  |  2  |  4  |  3  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
```

... and so on. When I run the code below, I get the following result in my browser. It looks like the associative array is being filled twice. I've seen this when I do the fetch array with MYSQLI_BOTH, but I should be getting just the associtive array with the code below.

```
|  Job Code  | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun |   Job Code  | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun | 
--------------------------------------------------------
|  1234-567  |  0  |  3  |  2  |  5  |  2  |  0  |  0  |
|  3214-431  |  0  |  2  |  4  |  3  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
```

Code...

```
function query2table( $dbcon, $query )
{
    // Connection is already made.
    $queryResult = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
    if( $queryResult )
    {
        echo "<TABLE cellpadding='5' cellspacing='1' border='1'><THEAD><TR>\n";
        while ($hdrrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult) )
        {
            foreach ($hdrrow as $hdr => $value) {
                echo "<th>";
                echo $hdr;
                echo "</th>";
            }
        }
        echo "</TR></THEAD>\n";
        mysqli_data_seek($queryResult, 0);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult,MYSQLI_NUM))
        {
            foreach( $row as $cell )
            {
                echo "<TD>$cell</TD>";
            }

            echo "    </TR>\n";
        }
        echo "</TABLE>\n";

    } else {
        $error = mysqli_error($dbcon);
        echo "\n<BR><BR>dbi_displayQuery - Error reading database: $error<BR><BR>\n";
    }
}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through all your rows and outputting the header row as many times as you have results:

```
while ($hdrrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult) )
```

For the header row, you just need to fetch one row and use that:

```
if ($hdrrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult) )
```